# Mysterious X509HostnameVerifier dependency

Tags: rest, maven, dependency-management

While extending a previously working project, I seemed to have muffed a maven dependency.

junit snippet:

```
Client interimClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget interim = interimClient.target(REST_TARGET_URL);
result persistedResult = interim.request()
                                .post(Entity.entity(testResult, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), Result.class);
Assert.assertEquals("A result should be persisted ", "TEST", persistedResult.getId());
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:116)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:164)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
```

I tried adding the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.0-alpha4</version>
</dependency>
```

...but then got

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
```

Given that this was working just a couple hours earlier, following each successive dependency error seems like sliding down the rabbit hole.  Hopefully this is a known jumping-off point that someone can help direct me on.  tiy.

Comment: Try `<version>4.5.1</version>` for `httpclient`.

Answer (score 4):

We were getting a similar error message when running JUnit tests.  Our dependency versions are coming from org.wildfly:wildfly-parent:10.0.0.Final.

The initial error was:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
```

Adding the following dependency resolved the initial error

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

We then received this second error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/X509HostnameVerifier
```

Adding the following dependency resolved the second (X509HostnameVerifier) error

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Once these two dependencies were added the problem was resolved.  The resteasy-client resolves to version 3.0.14.Final and the httpclient resolves to version 4.5 for org.wildfly:wildfly-parent:10.0.0.Final.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that my smattering of jax-rs related dependencies somehow mutated into causing this error.  I was able to get back into good standing after whittling them down into just the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```